# How to update .min.css files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap.min.css

I hope this isn't a dumb question but I've hit a wall. I am trying to modify the CSS for a Drupal 7 site that uses a bootstrap theme. I've updated the `.css` files, but the styles seem to be coming from the `.min.css` files, which are read-only.

How do I update the `.min.css` files?

Comment: You would normally include your own CSS file that is loaded *after* the bootstrap CSS, and overwrite the classes from bootstrap in your CSS file

Comment: @Michael Coker Right. I was just mentioning that the theme used is bootstrap for the record. So I edited the css files... what now?

Comment: Refresh your browser? I dunno, your question is really vague. Not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: So, I edited the css file, but there's an identical min.css file where the styles are being pulled from. I can't figure out how to update that file......

Comment: If you have a css file on your page that you can't update (whatever the min.css thing is you're referring to), include your own stylesheet *after* that file, and overwrite the CSS in your stylesheet. Refresh your browser. Problem solved. Also make sure you keep [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in mind.

Comment: You need to create a subtheme of the bootstrap theme.

Comment: Thanks @Achraf JEDAY. I'm actually working in the subtheme already. SO I'm hearing there isn't any way to update min files?

Comment: I am using the bootstrap theme in my site (D8) you need to update Sass files, not CSS using Gulp or Compass.

Comment: @Achraf JEDAY oh are min files sass related? I inherited a site with only css files, though.

Comment: Look for an scss folder in the root of your subtheme

Comment: also turn aggregation off from Drupal administration.

Comment: @Achraf JEDAY there is only a css folder

Comment: let's continue in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144605/discussion-between-jillian-hoenig-and-achraf-jeday).